# How can I suppress Google's messages when using ggmap with knitr?

Tags: r, knitr, ggmap

How can I suppress Google's messages in an output `.pdf` when using `ggmap` with a `knitr` `.Rnw` file? MWE code for `.Rnw` file used to generate a `.pdf` illustrating the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<>>=
library(ggmap)
qmap("empire state building", zoom=15, messaging=FALSE, source="google") 
@
\end{document}
```

In the resulting `.pdf`, the following (poorly formatted) messages appear:

```
Map from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=empire+state+building&zoom=15&size=%20640x640&scale=%202&maptype=terrain&sensor=false
Google Maps API Terms of Service : http://developers.google.com/maps/terms  
Information from URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=empire+state+building&sensor=false  
Google Maps API Terms of Service : http://developers.google.com/maps/terms
```

How can these messages be suppressed? I was hoping `messaging=FALSE` would do this.

Comment: would `suppressMessages` work?

Comment: `message = FALSE` not `messaging = FALSE`?

Comment: `messaging = FALSE` is specified in `ggmap` documentation. Separately, thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supress any messages for a code chunk using `message = FALSE`

```
<<themap, message = FALSE>>=
library(ggmap)
qmap("empire state building", zoom = 15, messaging = FALSE, source = "google") 
@
```

Suppresses these messages.

Looking at `ggmap::qmap`, it evaluates the arguments in `...` in what might be considered a non-standard way to allow the different `sources` to be used. It appears that `verbose` (an argument to `RgoogleMaps::GetMap` does not get parsed or passed, nor does `messaging` (an argument to get_googlemap`)